# jQuery - get difference in angle of parent for CSS counter-rotation of child

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, rotation

I am using the jQuery-ui plugin rotatable:
https://github.com/godswearhats/jquery-ui-rotatable

My goal is to have a rotatable parent element with counter rotation of a child, so the child appears to be non-rotating.

**Markup:**

```
<div class="prop"> // Rotatable element
    <div class="controls"> // Counter-rotated element
        <span class="forward">Forward</span>
        <span class="back">Back</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('.prop').rotatable({
    stop: function (element, ui) {
        console.log(ui.angle.stop);
    }
});
```

**Rotating .prop clockwise, full-circle and stopping every so-often logs:**

```
0.8878111523002155
2.09755867669314
2.6773906348383703
3.3422210195600486
4.164313303696719
4.679676340815534
5.244536132588575
-0.6508896063585539
-0.19499934637089922
0.2217151122145471
```

**Question being:**
How does `angle` differ from degrees (360)?  and how do i calculate the child's (.controls) counter-rotation so it seems fixed?

I'm assuming applying css transforms in .rotate()'s 'stop' callback would be an adequate solution, but I'm certainly open to any other suggestions.

**So far i have:**

```
function getCounterRotation(angle){

    return Math.floor(360 - angle * 6 * 10);

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Math sine, cosine?  Just thinking out loud...

Comment: Also, does it even need to counter spin.  How about positioning the non spinning item absolute as a sibling inside a shared container?

Comment: Based on your update, I'm guessing it uses radians, not degrees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a fiddle of an exemple you can use here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zajo6Lyx/1/

```javascript
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $('.controls').css('transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.stop + 'rad)');
        $('.controls').css('-moz-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.stop + 'rad)');
        $('.controls').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.stop + 'rad)');
        $('.controls').css('-o-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.stop + 'rad)');
    },
```

If you want to keep it blocked you should use this code:

```javascript
        rotate: function(event, ui) {
            $('.controls').css('transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.current + 'rad)');
            $('.controls').css('-moz-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.current + 'rad)');
            $('.controls').css('-webkit-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.current + 'rad)');
            $('.controls').css('-o-transform','rotate(' + -ui.angle.current + 'rad)');
        },
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I didn't expect it to be that simple.